# Django admin panel has no styling

Tags: python, django, django-admin

When I started my project and went to the admin panel the admin panel had no styling[image: the admin panel]

There is no styling as usual. What should I do to fix it. Thank you

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/, Show us minimal verifiable example including your staticfiles configuration and  way you are deploying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. run `python manage.py collectstatic` to collect the admin static files
2. ensure your webserver can serve static files from your `STATIC_DIR`

Comment: When I run that command it says that "This will overwrite existing files". Is it ok if I overwrite the current existing files?